# Superlative version or synonym of "Versatile"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for comparative/superlative versions of **versatile** - synonyms which should mean "more versatile" and "extremely versatile"

Here's the background:

Over on [meta.so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72507/new-badge-idea-versatile-related-to-stack-flair), I've proposed a new 3-tiered badge for users who have high rep across multiple SE sites.

At bronze I'd call it `Versatile`.
Can't think of titles for Silver and Gold.

I only have "Multifaceted" and "All-rounder" right now. 
Any other suggestions?

Comment: Going by the current badge convention, having strictly nouns would be a good idea.

Comment: I would only comment that "know-it-all" is a bit derogatory... either of "multifaceted" or "polymath" would be a nice badge name, IMHO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- polymath
- sage
- Da Vinci
- Renaissance Man (Person?)
- homo universalis
- swiss army knife
- protean

Comment: *polymath* is a truly excellent suggestion!

Comment: Going by your list, here would be my badge titles: bronze - *polymath*, silver - *Homo Universalis*, gold - *Proteus* (godlike status, beyond human!).

Comment: @Jimi Oke: Thanks for doing that classification, *Polymath* was a strong contender for Gold - as it was a new word (for me). I'll wait for the community votes on this.

Comment: Polymath sounds excellent to me for silver or gold.  Homo Universalis and Proteus/Protean don’t seem so good: Homo universalis is apt but obscure; Protean has the wrong connotations entirely — it suggests you can appear as many different things, not that you have many different skills.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, everyone. I'm surprised nobody's gone for "swiss army knife" :P

Comment: @PLL I believe "protean" has positive connotations (and the desired denotation) largely within the acting community.

Comment: On *Swiss Army Knife*: Well, while it indicates one can *do* many things, it does not necessarily indicate the person *knows* a lot!

Comment: @PLL: Indeed, but if *Proteus* has the ability to appear as many different personalities, he could certainly appear with different skills as well. The would-be Proteus appears on various SE sites with professional or near-professional knowledge on those many subjects.

Comment: @Jimi Oke: Polymath might lead to confusion as it has been previously [proposed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12603/badge-suggestion-polymath-gold-version-of-generalist) as a gold version of the Generalist badge.

Comment: I'll go in for *swiss army knife*. :)  (I would not put it at higher than bronze, though.)

Answer (score 4):

Some synonyms (positive, comparative or superlative) and related nouns:

- *well-rounded*
- *multifaceted*
- *multitalented*
- *resourceful*
- *Jack of many trades* (possibly bronze/silver)
- *Master of many trades* (possibly gold)
- *handy*

Answer (score 2):

Beyond inventing a word like "versatilitudinous", the best ideas I can come up with are "multitalented", "well-rounded", and "Jack-of-all-trades".

Answer (score 2):

“Jack of all trades” could be a good bronze.  Like many bronze badges, it’s not an unqualified complement; it has the desired connotation of “good at a lot of things”, but the implicit “…and master of none” keeps open the motivation to push on to the silver or gold.

Comment: but if you see some of the superhumans are actually a *master* in at least one site. http://stackexchange.com/leagues

Comment: Indeed, true!  Which is why the “master of none” is just suggestively hinted towards, not expressly implied :-)